# Is "And you!" a valid alternative to "You too!"?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, british-english

If someone says "Have a nice day!", can you just answer "And you!"? Does it mean the same as "You too!"?

Comment: Thank You very much guys! :) So basically You can answer "And You!" for "Have a good day!" or "Happy New Year!"*, right? *especially this one.

Comment: If someone say to me, have a good night. Can I reply elsewise.

Answer (score 2):

As a native English speaker, in the U.S., I'd offer "and you, as well" instead of "and you."

"And you," by itself, is almost never spoken by a native English speaker (in the U.S.), but appears quite often in spanish: 'y tu', or 'y usted."

The most common response would be, "You too!", or "Thanks, you too!"

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Technically, "And you" probably applies better in certain grammatical situations, especially where the preceding was in second person. Honestly, "and you" strikes me as a little archaic, in part because it's harder to use correctly and thus is generally less used.

"You too" is less formal, but probably applies in more situations, so I would encourage you to stick with that, but it's worth knowing what someone means if they say "and you."

Answer (score 1):

Answer: yes. (in the UK)

Having lived in both the US and the UK, my experience is that you would probably never hear this in the United States, however it is quite frequently used in the UK as an informal 'Same to you, thank you'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The first time I heard of this saying if from my building's concierge. He has an air of a classic British butler. It felt friendly polite and archaic at the same time.